# How to use vue-infinite-loading in Nuxt.js (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I developing web app in Nuxt.js (Vue.js)

first,
[vue init nuxt/express MyProject](https://github.com/nuxt/express)

**~page/help.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p v-for="item in list">
      Line:
      <span v-text="item"></span>
    </p>
    <infinite-loading :on-infinite="onInfinite" spinner="bubbles" ref="infiniteLoading"></infinite-loading>
   </div>
</template>
<script>
let InfiniteLoading = require('vue-infinite-loading')
export default {
  ...
  components: {
    InfiniteLoading
  },
  methods: {
    onInfinite: function () {
      setTimeout(() => {
      const temp = []

      for (let i = this.list.length + 1; i <= this.list.length + 20; i++) {
          temp.push(i)
        }
      this.list = this.list.concat(temp)
      this.$refs.infiniteLoading.$emit('$InfiniteLoading:loaded')
      }, 1000)
    }
  }
} 
</script>
```

and, Moving from '/home' to '/help'

> window is not defined

So, I tried the following

```
let InfiniteLoading;
if (process.BROWSER_BUILD) {
  InfiniteLoading = require('vue-infinite-loading')
}
```

result,

> Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.(found in InfiniteLoading)

**I've tried the nuxt.js document method.**
**However, I could not solve it.**
**I want to find a more accurate answer.**

help me, Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Just did it myself and works like a charm. See it in action on comment section at https://guessthatshit.com

Install:

```
npm install vue-infinite-scroll --save
```

Create file vue-infinite-scroll.js in plugins directory:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import InfiniteScroll from 'vue-infinite-scroll'

Vue.use(InfiniteScroll);
```

Update nuxt.config.js to include following entry:

```
plugins: [
    {src: '~plugins/vue-infinite-scroll.js', ssr: false}
],
```

HINT: Dont forget to set infinite-scroll-disabled="autoLoadDisabled" properly otherwise you may spam your load function.

I also recognized that (only on nuxt production, not in dev) HTML is written before variables are assigned through "props: ['commentsData'],". therefore autoscroll function is triggered before some variable exists. Fix this with:

```
    computed: {
        autoLoadDisabled() {
            return this.loading || this.commentsData.length === 0;
        },
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use NuxtJs with vue-infinite-loading, you need to create a file.js in plugin folder:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import InfiniteLoading from 'vue-infinite-loading/src/components/Infiniteloading.vue'
Vue.use(InfiniteLoading)
```

After, you create vendor build in nuxt.config.js:

```
build: {
   vendor: ['~/plugins/infiniteload.js']
},
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is working with NuxtJs

1. Add vue-infinite-loading as a plugin on your `plugins` folder
2. add this to `nuxt.config.js` file =>
   `{ src: '@/plugins/vue-infinite-loading.js', ssr: false }`
3. do not import it on your files or pages, just use it